# Touchable area of a UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Is there any way to define which area of a UIButton is clickable? In my case I would like to have PNGs with an alpha channel overlapping. These PNGs should act as buttons - but only where alpha is > 0. Is there a way?

Best
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. According to the Apple Human Interface Guidelines, all UI elements should behave in a consistent manner.

Answer (score 0):

[OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) is an awesome project that will give you a button that will only respond to taps that are in the images area.  I've messed with [Irregularly Shaped UIButtons](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html) and I think OBShapedButton is a little more accurate.  Not trying to bash on the other one at all.  I've used the other and it works just fine.  I've just seen a more accurate hit area with this one.